# I can't measure the size of richtextbox clearly

Tags: c#, string

I have a code that takes the resource.txt and brings it to the richtextbox one by one and (It should be like book pages) it should be cleared when the richtextbox is full in order to keep going without any click but my code writes the word and then clears the richtextbox what is the problem that I couldn't handle?

This is windows form application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private string Saying = Resource1.hikaye;


     private IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
     {
         var words = Saying.Split(' ');
         foreach (var word in words)
         {
             yield return word;
         }
     } 

    private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        string Document = Resource1.hikaye;
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Top 
                             | TextFormatFlags.Left 
                             | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak 
                             | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding 
                             | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;

        Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Document, richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Size, flags);

        foreach (var word in GetWords())
        {
             richTextBox1.Text += (word + ' ');
             await Task.Delay(50);
             if (textSize.Height >= richTextBox1.Height)
             {
                 richTextBox1.Clear();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are measuring the size before you start filling the TextBox. You have to recalculate it in the loop

Comment: foreach (var word in GetWords())
                 {
                     richTextBox1.Text += (word + ' ');
                     await Task.Delay(50);

                Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Size, flags);

                         if (textSize.Height >= richTextBox1.Height)
                          {
                             richTextBox1.Clear();
                          }


                   }

Comment: Thank you :)  It works.